# Convert String to Date with usage of SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, string, date

I want to convert a `String` to a `Date` but I get the following exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Jan 27 14:47:58 CET 2011"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:335)
    at de.datev.boxi.Main.run(Main.java:36)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.plugin.desktop.program.internal.ProgramWrapper.main(ProgramWrapper.java:174)
```

Which parameters should I use to format the String to a Date?

My program looks like:

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
    Date d1 = sdf.parse("Thu Jan 27 14:47:58 CET 2011");
    System.out.println(d1);
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing such "complicated" time stamps is always tricky in Java. I had the same experience.

Either Java has a problem parsing your Time-Zone.

Or even more likely the default locale doesn't match your time string, where I would suggest to add the English locale to your call:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

I would always suggest to add this parameter, as depending on the execution environment your applications could work on some and fail on other machines - depending on the default locale.

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```